# How can I return the control to the web page from which another php webpage was called

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Please see my code below.

How can I return the control to the `index.php` to an executable statement after the closing form tag to display query results on `index.php` page rather than code shown toward the end of `processData.php`?

I have searched through Google, this forum and have not seen a solution? Those familiar with Fortran, Visual Basic would appreciate the `return` statement that can be used to go back to the calling routine. Is there a statement similar to `return` to hand over the control to the calling web page in PHP?

Code for `index.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sales Report Summary</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Online Sales Report Demo
<br>
<br>
<form method="post" action="processData.php">
Enter Your Full Name:<input type="text" name= "author_name" />
<br> 
Enter Your eMail Address:<input type="text" name= "author_email" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
**//Question - How to return the control to a statement after </form> tag to print values instead of processData.php**
</body>
</html>
```

Code for `processData.php`:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$author = $email = "";

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

//Next extract the data for further processing

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$author = test_input($_POST['author_name']);
$email = test_input($_POST['author_email']);

//Next echo the Values Stored
echo "<br>";


echo "<br>Your Name:".$author;

echo "<br>Your Email Address:".$email;

}
?>

<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');


$sql = "SELECT Sales_Author, Sales_Date, Sales_Channel, Sales_Title, Sales_Unit, Sales_Royalty, Sales_Currency    
FROM Sales_tbl
WHERE Sales_Email= '" . $email . "' ORDER BY Sales_Date ASC";

$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(!$result )
{
 die('Could not fetch: ' . mysql_error());
}


?>
<table border="2" style="background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;">
<thead> <tr> <th>Date</th><th>Channel</th><th>Title</th><th>Units</th><th>Royalty</th><th>Currency</th></tr></thead><tbody>

<?php


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<tr>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Date']}</td>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Channel']}</td>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Title']}</td>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Unit']}</td>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Royalty']}</td>
     <td>{$row['Sales_Currency']}</td>
     </tr>\n"; }
     ?>

     </tbody></table>
     <?php
     mysql_close($conn);
     echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you cannot "return the control", you only can redirect back to "index.php" and include a parameter, that you can use in index.php to "behave" different.

Comment: and of course you can `include` one script in another one.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.Can you provide me an example/code/reference of redirect back and parameter inclusion on index.php to behave differently, as you have suggested!

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 0):

If I take your question literaly this is one possibility:

In `processData.php` put that link where ever you want it to be:

```
<a href="index.php?state=fromProcess">back to index.php</a>
```

then you can react on that parameter in index.php:

```
....
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
//Question - How to return the control to a statement after </form> tag to print values instead of processData.php**

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
        switch($_GET['state']) {
            case "fromProcess":
                 echo "I come from process!";
                 // do whatever you want to do
                 break;
            default:
                 echo "ERROR: undefined state submitted";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

There's of course also the possibility to redirect without clicking a link via

```
header("location: index.php?state=fromProcess");
// NOTE: This has to be before ANY output, and no output after that will be seen.
```

**But** I have the feeling, that you actually want to display data generated from processData in index.html.

Then you got at least two possibilities:

Include `processData.php` in `index.php` and wrap it in a

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['author_name'])) {
       include('processData.php');
       // process the data and make output
}
?>
```

Same is possible the other way round (but that's kinda tricky for what you want to do).

One general thing you have to keep in mind:
php scripts are scripts, basicly all on their own.
They are out of memory once they finished executing, so you cannot call a function of another script unless you include it into the current script (without autoload - but that not what you want).